# Expo Voice Recognition

Tags: react-native, expo, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, voice-recognition

I've been trying to implement Voice recognition on my Expo app, I've tried using a speech-to-text library called `react-native-voice` but it does not support Expo. Does anyone know any other library that I can use. I have read some articles on using Google's api but it is too complex for me and I prefer an easier alternative which can support Expo.

Answer (score 6):

Expo SDK42 actually allows us to use the `react-native-voice` plugin,
here is what i done

- yarn add @react-native-voice/voice
- modify your app.json with this `"expo": { "plugins": [ [ "@react-native-voice/voice", { "microphonePermission": "Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to access your microphone", "speechRecogntionPermission": "Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to securely recognize user speech" } ] ] }`

After that you can build your app with `expo run` and then use the `react-native-voice` plugin as normal

you can read more about that [here](https://docs.expo.dev/clients/getting-started/#customizing-your-runtime)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you can try **react-native-speech-recognition** from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-speech-recognition) it might work with Expo too

Answer (score 0):

I am doing a project very similar to yours. There is NO Expo library for speech-to-text. Either eject from Expo into Bare React Native or deploy the Google Speech to Text API in the cloud (I used Heroku) and send your voice info as a POST request to it.

Answer (score -3):

If you are using Expo, now you can use a module called Speech for voice recognition.
Docs are here https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/speech/

Comment: This module is for Text To Speech but we need Speech To Text in this topic